# Make UITableView imageView square?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview, imageview

I have a app that will populate a UITableView after the user takes a picture.

The UITableViewCell's image is that picture that the user takes. I would prefer these images to be square.

I have tried just about everything, here's some code:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:theImagePath];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.imageView.image = theImage;
```

Thanks!
Coulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one option would be to pass in a square image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(60.0f, 60.0f));
[fullSizeImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,60.0f, 60.0f)];

UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

you would probably want to only do this once for each image, and then cache the result.